# Data is always null when send from view to web api controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, model-view-controller

When I send data from my view to web api controller my ID fields are always got null in controller, below is my code

```
$scope.Create_Click = function (CategoryselectedItemvalue, SupplierSelectedItemvalue, Product_Name, Quantity_PerUnit, Reorder_Level, Unit_Price, Units_InStock, Units_OnOrder) {
            var CategoryID = parseInt(CategoryselectedItemvalue); 
            var SupplierID = parseInt(SupplierSelectedItemvalue); 
            var ProductName;
            var QuantityPerUnit;
            var ReorderLevel;
            var UnitPrice;
            var UnitsInStock;
            var UnitsOnOrder;
            Product = {
                CategoryID: CategoryID,
                SupplierID: SupplierID,
                ProductName: Product_Name,
                QuantityPerUnit: Quantity_PerUnit,
                ReorderLevel: Reorder_Level,
                UnitPrice: Unit_Price,
                UnitsInStock: Units_InStock,
                UnitsOnOrder: Units_OnOrder
            };
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/Products/PostProduct',
                data: JSON.stringify($scope.Product),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' }
            }).
            success(function (data) {
                alert("Record Added");
            }).
            error(function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            });
        };

    });
```

Below is my controller method (here when I recieved data CategoryID and SupplierID is always null)

```
[ActionName("PostProduct")]
        public IHttpActionResult PostProduct(Product product)
        {
            Product pro = new Product();
            pro.CategoryID = product.CategoryID;
            pro.SupplierID = product.SupplierID;
            pro.ProductName = product.ProductName;
            pro.QuantityPerUnit = product.QuantityPerUnit;
            pro.ReorderLevel = product.ReorderLevel;
            pro.UnitPrice = product.UnitPrice;
            pro.UnitsInStock = product.UnitsInStock;
            pro.UnitsOnOrder = product.UnitsOnOrder;
            if (repo.AddNewProduct(pro))
            {
                return Ok("Product Added");
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok("Error");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your header is 'application/json', I don't think there is any need of using `JSON.stringify` which basically converts json to a string and therefore, you cannot access your keys.

Just send your object as it is in JSON format.

Answer (score 2):

While stringifying data it should be in JSON format, where its key would be `product`(action parameter name)

```
data: JSON.stringify({product : $scope.Product}),
```

Or you don't need to stringify your data if you are using `Web.API`, you just only need to use `[FromBody]` attribute before you `Product` parameter in action.

```
[ActionName("PostProduct")]
public IHttpActionResult PostProduct([FromBody] Product product)
{
   //code is the same
}
```